# Whats wrong with this play view

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

My play view looks like this

```
@(productInfo: model.ProductInfo)(price: String)

@main("Product Info") {

    <h1>@productInfo.name</h1>
    <h1>Product Price: @price</h1>
    <h1>Product Attributes</h1>
    <div>
        @productInfo.attributes.map{(key, val) => <div>Product key: @key</div>}
    </div>
}
```

However on 'sbt compile' I get the following error

```
[error] /Users/asattar/Dev/work/StoreApp/app/views/productInfo.scala.html:9: illegal start of simple expression
[error]     @productInfo.attributes.map{(key, val) => <div>Product key: @key</div>}
[error]                                       ^
[error] /Users/asattar/Dev/work/StoreApp/app/views/productInfo.scala.html:11: ')' expected but '}' found.
```

productInfo.attributes is Map[String, String]

I am a noob to play, not sure what is happening over here. Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`val` is the valid Scala keyword. You cannot use Scala keyword for variable name.

Use `v` or `value` or `foo` etc